# Could I use magnets to lift or move something from a distance

Tags: magnetic-fields, estimation

Would it be possible to use magnets to cause some object to lift off the ground from a meter or two away? Let's assume that material cost is of no concern.

I am mostly interested in lifting or moving small objects around 100 grams,  magnetic objects only if that makes it easier.

Comment: What sort of object are you hoping to lift?

Comment: If you haven't already you should see the demonstrations of how strong an MRI machine is, which definitely shows the long distance force capable of a strong magnetic field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

But it's probably not practical to do it with a 'permanent' magnet.   You could definitely find one that will lift 100 grams from 2 meters away (it will be BIG and EXPENSIVE).  But once it gets 'stuck', you'll have a crazy hard time getting it UNSTUCK.

An electromagnet is how you would wanna do this.  You'll be able to control the attractive strength, and you can turn it on and off at will.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic force, just like gravitational force, is *a long-range non-contact force*, i.e. a force that acts over a distance. If you remember *second Newton's law of motion*, the object motion is described as:

$$\boxed{m \vec{a} = \sum_{k} \vec{F}_k}$$

where $\vec{F}_k$ are (all) forces exerted on the object, and $\vec{a}$ is object's acceleration vector which is in the same direction as the net force (vector sum).

For an object just sitting on the floor, there are two forces exerted on the object, namely (i) weight due to gravitational force, and (ii) normal force due to contact with the floor.

The answer to your question depends on the direction you apply the magnetic force from:

- If the object is to move vertically (off the ground), the magnetic force must overcome the object's weight;
- If the object is to move horizontally (parallel to the surface), the magnetic force must overcome the static friction force.

Note that there are some other forces that also act on the object:

- buoyancy can be neglected if object's density is large enough compared to air density;
- air drag can be neglected if object's velocity is small enough.